# How can I report cypress failed test to custom URL

Tags: cypress

I would like to report my failed cypress test to my URL.

For example to `www.myserver.com/failedtest`

How can I do it?

Is there any solution ready? I found only slack integration.

Comment: It's just JavaScript, why not write a plug-in: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide

Comment: Because I would like to reuse existing project/plugin. its a reason why I am asking SO.

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are off-topic here, if that's all you want I suggest you search on NPM.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this awesome answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69382872/1757737

The gist of it:

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {

    if (test.state === 'failed') {
        const details = { error: runnable.err.message}

        fetch('https://somewebhook', {method: 'POST', mode: 'no-cors', body: JSON.stringify(details)});
    }
})
```