# Send a REST message for each Cypress test result

Tags: cypress

Is there a way to call a REST api based for each cypress test result?

We have a zephyr test definition system, and we must use it's API (https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-server/api-docs/v1/ ) to change the status of each testcase our testers defined, as part of the automation processes we have in our company.

In my research the only solution we found was to use a Reporter (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters) and then parse the results with a small script which generates the said REST calls for each test result.

I was wondering: is there any more elegant solution to call the zephyr app directly, via Cypress maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what info zephyr requires, but there's plenty of hooks/events you can use.

For example (at the top of the spec or in /support/index.js)

```js
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {

  console.log('test,runnable', test, runnable)

  const details = {
    projectKey: Cypress.env('zephyr-project-key'),
    testName: test.invocationDetails.relativeFile,
    status: test.status,
    error: runnable.err.message,
    retries: runnable.retries.length,
    duration: test.wallClockDuration,
    startTime: test.wallClockStartedAt
  }
  
  cy.request('POST', 'api/end/point', { body: details })
  // or native fetch('POST',...) if a particular hook complains about using cy.request
})
```

There's also

```js
on('after:run', (results) => {
  /* ... */
})

on('after:spec', (spec, results) => {
  /* ... */
})

on('after:screenshot', (details) => {
  /* ... */
})
```

Or (technically inside the test)

```js
afterEach(() => {
  const test = cy.state('test')
  const runnable = cy.state('runnable')
  /* ... */
})
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, cy.request just didn't do anything for me, didn't send a request nor did it complain... Fetch worked tho, but like this: `fetch('https://somewebhook', {mode: 'no-cors'})`

Comment: I had a feeling about that - if the test has finished, anything `cy.*` probably does not work any more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was wondering, if there is any way to determine the result of a test and THEN send the REST request?  It seems that these requests are only available durring the test :\

Comment: Some or most of those hooks (particularly `test:after:run`) should occur after the test completes. At least, I observed a value in `test.status` which logically would only be filled in after the test finishes.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will write a PoC latest next week and will confirm if this indeed works.

Comment: Did it work @ForestG ? I need same thing but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sebastian yes. I did not write the poc in the end, but one of my collegues confirmed that it works.

Comment: @ForestG I couldn't make it work buy maybe it is on my end. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Sebastian I have added some examples from our code that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

in the `index.js`:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('after:spec', async (spec, results) => {
    /**
     * spec file data
     */
    const cycleName = getCycleName(spec);

    /**
     * CyPress test results parse
     */
    const zephyrResults = await parserSpecResults(results);
    const data = JSON.stringify(zephyrResults);

    /**
     * send data to our server
     */
    await sendTestResults(data, cycleName);
  });
};
```

And our `sendTestResults`:

```
async function sendTestResults(sendData, cycleName) {
  options.path = `/rest/atm/1.0/testrun/${cycleName}/testresults`; // our zephyr's dynamic endopints
  options.method = 'POST';
  options.headers['Content-Length'] = sendData.length;

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response to sending test results to Zephyr : ', `${chunk}`);
        resolve(res);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Error the send test result to Zephyr: ', error);
      reject(error);
    });

    req.write(sendData);
    req.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. You absolutely rock!